# Validation of regex return false

Tags: java, regex

Why does this return false for any normal word I enter?

```
if(!guestbook.getName().matches("[a-zA-Z0-9\\s]")) {
        errors.rejectValue("name", "stringFormat.falseCharacters", "You are only allowed to use numbers, letters and spaces for the name.");
    }
```

I must be missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex only matches one-character long Strings.
To match one or more number of characters change it to:

```
"[a-zA-Z0-9\\s]+"
```

You might also find this (imo great) **[Regular-Expressions reference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/)** useful.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is `[a-zA-Z0-9\\s]+`. Add `+` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Because you should add the '+' at the end of your regex, otherwise you are requesting the match of just one character.

Answer (score 0):

In regular expressions you use the `+` at the end of your range to specify "more than one" while in your case you probe for only for expressions with a length of one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex "^[A-Za-z0-9\s]+$",

```
if(!guestbook.getName().matches("^[A-Za-z0-9\\s]+$")) {
    errors.rejectValue("name", "stringFormat.falseCharacters", "You are only allowed to use numbers, letters and spaces for the name.");
}
```